# Concerned about nested classes

Tags: android

I am working on a client server application, the server is in Delphi and I am using indy and using packed records for sending/receiving data, on the Android side I was able to find a library named javolution for converting the bytes array to class form so I can easily read the data from received packets or send data.

A normal Packet class looks like this:

```
class clsCommunicatorPacket extends Struct{
    Unsigned16 signature = new Unsigned16();
    Unsigned32 version = new Unsigned32();
    Unsigned8 dataType = new Unsigned8();
    Unsigned16 bufferSize = new Unsigned16();

    public boolean isPacked() {
         return true; // MyStruct is packed.
     }

    public ByteOrder byteOrder() {
         // TopStruct and its inner structs use hardware byte order.
         return ByteOrder.nativeOrder();
    }
}
```

Everything is working as it is supposed to so far and am having no issue, but there will be more than a 100 types of packets and I need to store them in one place so I can access/create it from any activity for sending/receiving.

What I am thinking of doing is create a class file lets say clsAllPackets and then put all the packet classes in that class file.

And when I need to access a specific packet class I can instantiate it like this:

```
clsCommunicatorPacket Pck = new clsAllPackets().new clsCommunicatorPacket();
```

So every time I need a class packet I have to instantiate the whole upper class too...

I want to know what will be the consequences of this and how will this effect the performance of the application and what is the best alternative performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the nested class static, it can be instantiated without having an instance of its outer class. Also, that syntax for instantiating a nested class is incorrect, it should be

```
new clsAllPackets.clsCommunicatorPacket();
```